# AngularJS http post won't send data if all form fields are populated

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-model

I am using AngularJS. I have select tag on my form. On change I call function that sends http post and retrieves some data. It works when I before everything select value from select box, then it gets back data. But if I populate just one other field and then change dropdown list value, it won't send http post. I really don't understand what could be problem.

Here is part of my form:

```
                .
                .
                .

<div class="form-group" >
                    <label>NUM<span class="error">*</span></label><span data-ng-show="user.userForm1.NUM.$touched && user.userForm1.NUM.$invalid "  class="error">Required</span>
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="NUM" data-ng-model="user.NUM" required   data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{13,13}$/" data-ng-value="NUM"/>
                </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="control-label">City<span class="error">*</span></label><span data-ng-show="user.userForm1.selectedCity.$touched && user.userForm1.selectedCity.$invalid" class="error">Required</span>                            
                        <select  ng-change="sendSelection()"  data-ng-model="user.selectedCity" class="form-control" name="selectedCity" required data-ng-value="user.selectedCity" >
                            <option value="">Chose city</option>
                            <option >City1</option>
                             <option >City2</option>
                             <option >City3</option>
                             <option >City4</option>

                          </select> 
    </div>

                  .
                  .
                  .
```

Here is my function inside controller:

```
$scope.sendSelection = function() {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'add.php',
            withCredentials: true,
            data: "selection="+$scope.user.selectedCity,
            datatype: "json",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            alert(data);
        });
         }
```

It all works on localhost but when I put it on real server it has problem that I mentioned above.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint at the beginning of the `sendSelection` function? I would step through that to ensure it is being called. Also look at the `network` tab of the Chrome developer tools and see if the `POST` is being sent. If it is sent and just waiting for a response forever, there is a problem with the server not AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you for response. I will try this now then come back here.

Comment: Can you give me some directions how can easily put brakpoint on sendSelection() ?

Comment: I use Google Chrome. In most browsers `F12` pulls up the developer console. You can click line numbers of source code in the sources tab to set breakpoints. I would just google how to set breakpoints in your preferred browser.